# Why is Quantopian's pf.create_full_tear_sheet() function giving me a DateTimeArray error?

Tags: python, pandas, quantopian

I'm trying to run Pyfolio's `pf.create_full_tear_sheet(df_returns)` function on my own set of returns data `df_returns` (pandas dataframe) which looks like this:

[image]

However I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with DatetimeArray is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`
```

I suspect the date format might be the problem, hence I checked the datatype:

```
In: df_returns['Date'].dtype
Out: dtype('<M8[ns]')

In: df_returns['% Returns'].dtype
Out: dtype('float64')
```

Could it be that I'm not specifying the benchmark data in `pf.create_full_tear_sheet(df_returns)` that's causing the error too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really reproduce your error. It might have to do with the fact that you are passing a full dataframe: according to [Pyfolio's API reference](https://www.quantopian.com/docs/api-reference/pyfolio-api-reference#pyfolio.create_full_tear_sheet) the `returns` argument has to be passed as a `pd.Series`.

If I pass just the `Returns %` column it gives proper output. Try:

```py
df_returns = df_returns.set_index('Date')
pf.create_full_tear_sheet(df_returns['% Returns'])
```

It is good to note that I found the package dependencies to be quite outdated:

- I had to manually install `zipline` which degrades `pandas` back to `0.22.0`.
- `matplotlib` is throwing a lot of deprecated warnings since `3.2.x` so I degraded it to `3.1.x`.
- Use of `.argmin()` is deprecated and throws warnings. [This issue has been known since 2019-05-24](https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio/issues/601).

This leads me to believe `pyfolio` can be very sensitive to your environment. Did you install it using the [virtual environment instructions](https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio#installation) in the docs?

Comment: Hi jorijnsmit.. with your suggestion i managed to get the Annual Return to Dail value risk stats. but it stops there and doesn't produce any charts. I get this error ````'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'```` Similar to the final post in this thread: https://www.quantopian.com/posts/trouble-with-basic-pyfolio-tearsheet

Comment: create_full_tear_sheet() requires a full pandas dataframe format to be passed in..

Comment: Then only set a proper index and pass the whole `df_returns`.

Comment: ````ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().````

Comment: Expanded my answer. Here's a working example: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Umi9fC5srxxssrGbFJoNjFsxqBO-s_eO

Comment: i realized it was my local zipline library giving me the issues...using colab as u indirectly suggested worked!